# How to use Redis with Ktor to do text searches with JSON data types?

Tags: json, kotlin, search, redis, ktor

Looking for help on how to setup Ktor to work with Redis to handle text searches on JSON types.

The libraries and sample code is all written for Java.

Looking for help specifically for doing text searches on JSON objects.

ie: `redis.ftSearch(query, searchOptions)`

Looking at the Redis docs, its all for Java, nothing about Kotlin. I cannot find any kotlin-specific Redis libraries.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching GH and trial and error, I found a couple libraries to use for this that are well supported.

// build.gradle.kts

```
dependencies {
    // Lettuce for Redis
    implementation("io.lettuce:lettuce-core:6.2.6.RELEASE")
    implementation("com.redis:lettucemod:3.6.3") // Extension library for Lettuce
}
```

// RedisSearchCommands.kt

```
// Define the Redis Search Commands
// Yes, its odd that we have to define the commands this way, but it's how it works.
interface RedisSearchCommands : Commands {
    @Command("FT.CREATE")
    @CommandNaming(strategy = CommandNaming.Strategy.DOT)
    fun ftCreate(index: String, vararg args: String): String

    @Command("FT.CONFIG SET")
    @CommandNaming(strategy = CommandNaming.Strategy.DOT)
    fun ftConfigSet(key: String, value: String): String
}
```

// Application.kt

```
fun Application.module() {
    val redisClient: RedisModulesClient = RedisModulesClient.create("redis://localhost:6379")
    val redisConnection: StatefulRedisModulesConnection<String, String> = redisClient.connect()

    val redisSyncCommand: RedisModulesCommands<String, String> = redisConnection.sync()
    val redisCoroutineCommand = redisConnection.coroutines()
    val redisReactiveCommand = redisConnection.reactive()

    // setup the search commands not included in libraries
    val redisSearchCommands = RedisCommandFactory(redisConnection).getCommands(RedisSearchCommands::class.java)

    // allow one character strings for FT.SEARCH
    redisSearchCommands.ftConfigSet("MINPREFIX", "1") 

    // Build the JSON Text search indexes
    try {
        // check if index exists
        val result = redisSyncCommand.ftInfo("users_index")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // setup json text search index
        val result = redisSyncCommand.ftCreate(
            "users_index",
            CreateOptions.builder<String, String>()
                .prefix("user:")
                .on(CreateOptions.DataType.JSON)
                .build(),
            Field.tag("$.id")  // note: TAGs do not separate words/special characters
                .`as`("id")
                .build(),
            Field.tag("$.email")
                .`as`("email")
                .build(),
            Field.text("$.name")
                .`as`("name")
                .sortable()
                .withSuffixTrie()  // for improved search (go -> going, goes, gone)
                .build()
        )

        if (result != "OK") {
            ktorLogger.error("Error creating index: $result")
        }
    }
    // ...application continues below...
```

// Run some basic tests

```
    val resultRedisAdd1 = redisSyncCommand.jsonSet(
        "user:1",
        "$", // path
        """
            {
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001",
                "email": "chris@alpha.com",
                "name": "Chris"
            }
        """.trimIndent()
    )
    println("resultRedisAdd1: $resultRedisAdd1")

    val resultRedisAdd2 = redisSyncCommand.jsonSet(
        "user:2",
        "$",
        """
            {
                "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002",
                "email": "billy@beta.com",
                "name": "Billy"
            }
        """.trimIndent()
    )
    println("resultRedisAdd2: $resultRedisAdd2")

    val escapedSearchId = "0000-000000000001".escapeRedisSearchSpecialCharacters()
    val resultIdSearch = redisSyncCommand.ftSearch(
        "users_index",
        "@id:{*$escapedSearchId*}" // search for '0000-000000000001' in id
    )
    println("resultIdSearch: $resultIdSearch")

    val resultTagSearch = redisSyncCommand.ftSearch(
        "users_index",
        "@email:{*ch*}" // search for 'ch' in email, note use curly-braces for TAG type
    )
    println("resultTagSearch: $resultTagSearch")

    val resultTextSearch = redisSyncCommand.ftSearch(
        "users_index",
        "@name:*bi*" // search for 'bi' in name, note NO curly-braces for TEXT type
    )
    println("resultTextSearch: $resultTextSearch")

    @Serializable
    data class UserSearchResult(
        val id: String,
        val email: String,
        val name: String,
    )

    val resultArray = resultTagSearch.map { resultMap ->
        val resultValue = resultMap.get("$") as String
        jsonConfig.decodeFromString<UserSearchResult>(resultValue)
    }
    println("resultArray: $resultArray")

    // ...application continues below...
```

##### // Setup the Ktor application web server to respond to http requests for Redis content

```
    routing {
        route("/redis") {

            get("/keys") {
                val keys = redisCoroutineCommand.keys("*")
                val output: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
                keys.collect { key ->
                    output += key
                }
                call.respondJson(mapOf("keys" to output.toString()))
            }

            get("/jsonGet") {
                val key = call.request.queryParameters["key"]
                key ?: run {
                    call.respondJson(mapOf("error" to "Missing key"), HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                    return@get
                }
                val paths = call.request.queryParameters["paths"] ?: "$"

                val value = redisReactiveCommand.jsonGet(key, paths) ?: run {
                    call.respondJson(mapOf("error" to "Key not found"), HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    return@get
                }
                call.respondJson(mapOf("key" to key, "value" to (value.block()?.toString() ?: "null")))
            }

            get("/jsonSet") {
                val key = call.request.queryParameters["key"] ?: run {
                    call.respondJson(mapOf("error" to "Missing key"), HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                    return@get
                }
                val paths = call.request.queryParameters["paths"] ?: "$"
                val value = call.request.queryParameters["value"] ?: run {
                    call.respondJson(mapOf("error" to "Missing value"), HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                    return@get
                }

                val result = redisReactiveCommand.jsonSet( key, paths, value) ?: run {
                    call.respondJson(mapOf("error" to "Failed to set key"), HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                    return@get
                }
                call.respondJson(mapOf("success" to Json.encodeToString(result.block())))
            }

            get("/jsonFind") {
                val index = call.request.queryParameters["index"] ?: run {
                    call.respondJson(mapOf("error" to "Missing index"), HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                    return@get
                }
                val query = call.request.queryParameters["query"] ?: run {
                    call.respondJson(mapOf("error" to "Missing query"), HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                    return@get
                }

                val result =
                    redisSyncCommand.ftSearch(
                        index,
                        query,
                        SearchOptions.builder<String, String>()
                            .limit(0, 100)
                            .withSortKeys(true)
                            .build()
                    ) ?: run {
                        call.respondJson(mapOf("error" to "Failed to find key"), HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                        return@get
                    }
                val searchResults: List<Map<String, String>> =
                    result.map { document ->
                        document.keys.map { key ->
                            key to document.get(key).toString()
                        }.toMap()
                    }
                call.respondJson(mapOf("success" to Json.encodeToString(searchResults)))
            }
        }
    }
}

fun String.escapeRedisSearchSpecialCharacters(): String {
    val escapeChars =
        """
        ,.<>{}[]"':;!@#$%^&*()-+=~"
        """.trimIndent()
    var result = this

    escapeChars.forEach {
        result = result.replace(it.toString(), "\\$it")
    }

    return result
  }

suspend fun ApplicationCall.respondJson(
  map: Map<String, String> = mapOf(),
  status: HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
) {
    respondText(jsonConfig.encodeToString(map), ContentType.Application.Json, status)
}
// end of application.
```

#### Start the Ktor server, and you can use any browser (or postman) to do the following commands:

In Browser:

- To get json object in redis database

  - http://localhost:8081/redis/jsonGet?key={keyId}&paths={paths}
  - Example:
  - http://localhost:8081/redis/jsonGet?key=user:1&paths=$
  - http://localhost:8081/redis/jsonGet?key=user:1&paths=.name
- To set json object in redis database

  - http://localhost:8081/redis/jsonSet?key={keyId}&paths={paths}&value={value}
  - Example
  - http://localhost:8081/redis/jsonSet?key=user:1&paths=$.name&value=Jimmy
- To query json object fields

  - http://localhost:8081/redis/jsonFind?index={index}&query=@{field}:{searchQuery}
  - Example
  - http://localhost:8081/redis/jsonFind?index=users_index&query=%27@name:bil*%27
- To Dump all keys in redis database

  - http://localhost:8081/redis/keys

Example code on gh:

https://github.com/realityexpander/com.realityexpander.ktor-redis-text-search